# How change From field in Postfix

Tags: server, email, postfix

I have own server and installed Postfix. When I send message in "From" field I have next:

`email1@example.com (Username)`

When other server receive this message it this that email1@example.com and Username - different peoples. How I can change current "From" field to this:

`Username <email1@example.com>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may depend on how you send email (what client you are using). If you're sending it from command line using `mail` or `mailx` you can use `-r` and append the information like so:

```
mail -s "Subject" -r "Username <email@example.com>" recipient
```

Don't forget to put the part past `-r` in double quotes.